# How to Upload a Profile photo in base64 format For Community Users Using ConnectApi.UserProfiles.setPhoto

Tags: upload, photo, salesforce-communities

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFQSW.png)Am Uploading Profile Photo for Community Users in base64 format By Using ConnectApi.UserProfiles.setPhoto Method. But am getting "ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: The file you uploaded doesn't appear to be a valid image" This error, Help me to Fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the below method:

```
public PageReference upload() {
    Blob b;
    document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // put it in running user's folder
    try {
        document.type = 'jpg';
        document.IsPublic = true;
        insert document;
        // ImageId = '06990000001HnuB';
        b = document.Body;
        //ConnectApi.ChatterUsers newPhoto = new ConnectApi.ChatterUsers();
    } catch (DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error uploading file'));
        return null;
    } finally {
        document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
        document = new Document();
    }
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'File uploaded successfully : ' + b));
    String communityId = null;
    String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    //ID fileId = ImageId;
    // Set photo
    ConnectApi.Photo photo = ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(communityId, userId, new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(b, 'image/jpg', 'userImage.jpg'));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This post is what is called a "code dump answer" where you only provide code and do not offer any additional explanation of how it solves the issue. Your post would be improved, for example, if you explain what the key functionality is.

Comment: Also, the code in its current state does not compile. You have not declared the variable 'document'.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, there isn't too much detail so I'm not too sure about your problem. I solved the problem using the code below. Modify as needed.

```
public static Boolean updateUserProfilePic(String userProfilePicString, String userId, String fileType){
Boolean updateSuccessful = true;

System.debug('-------------' + userProfilePicString.length());
try{
    Blob blobImage = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(userProfilePicString);

    ConnectApi.BinaryInput fileUpload = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(blobImage, 'image/jpg', 'userImage.jpg');
    ConnectApi.Photo photoProfile = ConnectApi.UserProfiles.setPhoto(null, userId,  fileUpload);
}
catch(Exception exc){
    updateSuccessful = false;
}

return updateSuccessful;
```

}